# Google Cloud Function Throwing Weird Error

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Is anyone here familiar with Google Cloud Functions?  I read their documentation and based on that, I customized my script to try to work in their hosted environment.

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime

So, my Python script looks like this.

```
def main():

    requests
    numpy
    pandas
    datetime
    requests
    pandas_gbq
    xml.etree.ElementTree


    # authentication: working....
    login = 'my_email' 
    password = 'my_password'


    AsOfDate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

    #step into URL
    REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.business.com/report-api/device=779142&rdate=Yesterday'
    response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=(login, password))
    xml_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore') 

    #tree = etree.parse(xml_data)
    root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(xml_data)

    # start collecting root elements and headers for data frame 1
    desc = root.get("Description")
    frm = root.get("From")
    thru = root.get("Thru")
    loc = root.get("locations")
    loc = loc[:-1]
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame([['From:',frm],['Through:',thru],['Location:',loc]])
    df1.columns = ['S','Analytics']
    #print(df1)

    # start getting the analytics for data frame 2
    data=[['Goal:',root[0][0].text],['Actual:',root[0][1].text],['Compliant:',root[0][2].text],['Errors:',root[0][3].text],['Checks:',root[0][4].text]]
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    df2.columns = ['S','Analytics']
    #print(df2)

    # merge data frame 1 with data frame 2
    df3 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
    #print(df3)

    # append description and today's date onto data frame
    df3['Description'] = desc
    df3['AsOfDate'] = AsOfDate


    # push from data frame, where data has been transformed, into Google BQ
    pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df3, 'Metrics', 'analytics', chunksize=None, reauth=False, if_exists='append', private_key=None, auth_local_webserver=False, table_schema=None, location=None, progress_bar=True, verbose=None)
    print('Execute Query, Done!!')

main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Also, my requirements.txt looks like this.

```
requests
numpy
pandas
datetime
requests
pandas_gbq
xml.etree.ElementTree
```

My script has been working fine for the past 2+ months, but I need to run it on my laptop each day.  To get away from this manual process, I am trying to get this running on the cloud.  The problem is that I keep getting an erorr message that reads: `TypeError: main() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

To me, it looks like no arguments are given and no arguments are expected, but somehow Google is saying 1 argument is given.  Can I modify my code slightly to get this to work, or somehow bypass this seemingly benign error?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following takes your code and changes it to run in Google Cloud Functions using an HTTP trigger. You can then use Google Cloud Scheduler to call your function on schedule. You will also need to create a `requirements.txt` with the modules that you need to import. See this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/python-runtime) for more information.

```
def handler(request):

    import requests
    import numpy
    import pandas
    import datetime
    import requests
    import pandas_gbq
    import xml.etree.ElementTree


    # authentication: working....
    login = 'my_email' 
    password = 'my_password'


    AsOfDate = datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m-%d-%Y')

    #step into URL
    REQUEST_URL = 'https://www.business.com/report-api/device=779142&rdate=Yesterday'
    response = requests.get(REQUEST_URL, auth=(login, password))
    xml_data = response.text.encode('utf-8', 'ignore') 

    #tree = etree.parse(xml_data)
    root = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(xml_data)

    # start collecting root elements and headers for data frame 1
    desc = root.get("Description")
    frm = root.get("From")
    thru = root.get("Thru")
    loc = root.get("locations")
    loc = loc[:-1]
    df1 = pandas.DataFrame([['From:',frm],['Through:',thru],['Location:',loc]])
    df1.columns = ['S','Analytics']
    #print(df1)

    # start getting the analytics for data frame 2
    data=[['Goal:',root[0][0].text],['Actual:',root[0][1].text],['Compliant:',root[0][2].text],['Errors:',root[0][3].text],['Checks:',root[0][4].text]]
    df2 = pandas.DataFrame(data)
    df2.columns = ['S','Analytics']
    #print(df2)

    # merge data frame 1 with data frame 2
    df3 = df1.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
    #print(df3)

    # append description and today's date onto data frame
    df3['Description'] = desc
    df3['AsOfDate'] = AsOfDate


    # push from data frame, where data has been transformed, into Google BQ
    pandas_gbq.to_gbq(df3, 'Metrics', 'analytics', chunksize=None, reauth=False, if_exists='append', private_key=None, auth_local_webserver=False, table_schema=None, location=None, progress_bar=True, verbose=None)
    # print('Execute Query, Done!!')

    # Normally for an HTTP trigger you would return a full HTML page here
    # <html><head></head><body>you get the idea</body></html>
    return 'Execute Query, Done!!'
```

Comment: Thanks.  I just plugged it in and got this error message:  ' Deployment failure:

Build failed: {"error": {"canonicalCode": "INVALID_ARGUMENT", "errorMessage": "`pip_download_wheels` had stderr output:\n  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement xml.etree.ElementTree (from -r requirements.txt (line 6)) (from versions: )\nNo matching distribution found for xml.etree.ElementTree (from -r requirements.txt (line 6))\n\nerror: `pip_download_wheels` returned code: 1", "errorType": "InternalError", "errorId": "4B6915C4"}}'
I saw that a couple times earlier today.

Comment: I did not check your import statements. The error means that Cloud Functions cannot resolve the package `xml`. Run your code thru `pylint` and fix all warnings and errors. This will also double check your import statements.

Comment: That's what I thought.  It seem like this is somewhat of a new offering, and as such, very immature.  I can come up with a work-around, for sure.  I'm looking forward to this thing being built out much more than it is right now.  Thanks for the help with this!!

Comment: `xml.etree.ElementTree` is [not a valid package on PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/xml.etree.ElementTree/), it's a standard library module: https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.html

Answer (score 1):

You're misunderstanding how Cloud Functions works.  It doesn't let you simply run arbitrary scripts.  You write triggers that respond to HTTP requests, or when something changes in your Cloud project.  That doesn't seem to be what you're doing here.  Cloud Functions deployments don't use main().

You might want to read the [overview documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/overview) to get an understanding of what Cloud Functions is used for.

If you're trying to run something periodically, consider writing an HTTP trigger and have that invoked by some cron-like service at the rate you want.

Comment: Yes, yes, you're exactly right. I'm trying to get cron to run my script from a server. That's what I want to do. How can I do that?

Comment: Start learning about HTTP triggers.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/http